# How to make the effect of these two commands permanent?

Tags: wireless, 17.10, realtek-wireless, rtl8723be

How to make the effect of these commands permanent so that it persists even after rebooting?

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Note: `echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf` does not work.

I followed [this tutorial](https://connectwww.com/how-to-solve-realtek-rtl8723be-weak-wifi-signal-problem-in-ubuntu/4625/) to solve a problem with weak wi-fi signal.

Comment: If the module is loaded at initramfs time, so you should run `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all` after the `echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf`  command

Comment: Please edit to include results for the [wireless script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665)

Comment: @Jeremy31 here it is https://pastebin.com/2upzAgXD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a second conf file in /etc/modprobe.d/ telling it to use ant_sel=1

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: That configuration file is most probably a leftover from all the way back when I was using 16.10. In both 16.10 and 17.04 the antenna that worked was 1, but in 17.10 it became 2 for some reason which I don't know.